# response from HTTP Request cannot convert from string to JSON

Tags: json, http

This is the function of the http.request, as follow:

```
var post_req =http.request(options,function(res){
    console.log('STATUS:'+res.statusCode);
    console.log('HEADERS: '+JSON.stringify(res.headers));
    var str ='';
    res.setEncoding('utf8');
    res.on('data',function (chunk){
        str += chunk;

    });
    res.on('end',function(){
        console.log("message="+str);
    });
    res.on('error',function(e){

    });
    var token= JSON.parse(str);
    console.log(token);
```

This is the error I got from the console, can anybody tell me what's wrong with my code?

```
undefined:0

^
SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input
    at Object.parse (native)
    at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (/Users/guojiaqi/Documents/workspace/ejs/APIintegration.js:27:18)
    at ClientRequest.g (events.js:180:16)
    at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:95:17)
    at HTTPParser.parserOnIncomingClient [as onIncoming] (http.js:1692:21)
    at HTTPParser.parserOnHeadersComplete [as onHeadersComplete] (http.js:121:23)
    at CleartextStream.socketOnData [as ondata] (http.js:1587:20)
    at CleartextStream.read [as _read] (tls.js:513:12)
    at CleartextStream.Readable.read (_stream_readable.js:340:10)
    at EncryptedStream.write [as _write] (tls.js:368:25)
```

Comment: Is the `str` variable empty? It looks like you're using event handlers to read the data from the network stream but you're not waiting for those to finish when you use `JSON.parse()`. Perhaps move `JSON.parse(str)` into `res.on('end', ...)`.

Comment: @Pluto Thanks man, it worked, please make this as an answer so I can give you a check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `str` variable is empty because you're using event handlers to read data from the network stream but you're not waiting for those to finish when you start doing stuff with `str`. Move `JSON.parse(str)` inside of `res.on('end', ...)` so that you can parse the JSON after you've finished downloading.